# Dynamically updating a progress bar in VB

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio

Hello I am a novice / mediocre VB programmer and I made a timer that simply need to update it self every second.

I started having doubts about weather or not it was working so I applied a msg box to my timers code it went off every second updating it self but the progress bar wont? why?

```
Dim power As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim percent As Single = power.BatteryLifePercent
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Value = percent * 100
    Label1.Text = percent * 100
End Sub
```

I have a power status and percent that takes the status and turn into a usable percentage then the progress bar uses that percentage but isnt updating like the msgBOX does why?

Comment: Try adding `ProgressBar1.Refresh` after setting the value so it repaints

Comment: Code works as posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your timer is probably working well and all, but you don't show where/how you get the updated value of `SystemInformation.PowerStatus.BatteryLifePercent`.

Maybe you're doing this somewhere else in your code, but as it is posted, you're always displaying the same value, so of course the progressbar is never going to change.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your question, everything should be working ok but I cant see that you have added `Timer1.Interval = 1000` however you may have but this with the designer and not the coding side, however nevertheless here is how I did this project so you could see my working example just so you can be sure, If you have any problems let me know and i will do my best to help you out :)

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Timer1 As New Timer
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick()
    Dim POWER As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
    Dim PERCENT As Single = POWER.BatteryLifePercent
    Dim ONCHARGE As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
    ProgressBar1.Value = PERCENT * 100
    Label1.Text = "Power Remaining: " & PERCENT * 100 & "%"
    If ONCHARGE.PowerLineStatus = PowerLineStatus.Online Then
        Label2.Text = "Currently: Charging"
    Else
        Label2.Text = "Currently: Not Charging"
    End If
    End Sub
    End Class
```

I added a Progressbar and two labels to the form, one of which is the computer battery and another of which will tell the user if the cable is unplugged in or not, i know you didnt ask for the cable status but i added it just incase you needed it :)
Happy Coding

Comment: The OP wanted to run it every second, so that would be `Timer1.Interval = 1000`.  You should override the OnLoad method instead of handling the form event, and your Tick method should include the proper parameters.